# Codeigniter 4 customized route is showing me a 404 error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

i'm using CodeIgniter 4 and having trouble creating a route

I have this url
/Show/post/100008
But I want to route it to this
/post/100008

I've tried
$routes->get('/post/(:num)', 'Show::post/(:num)');
but i'm getting 404 error when typing /post/100008 url only

Is the route correct or is there any other solution for it?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried $routes->get('/post/(:num)', 'Show::post/$1');?

Comment: Just tried replacing with $1 and problem solved! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The solution is by changing the line to

`$routes->get('/post/(:num)', 'Show::post/$1');`

Codeigniter 4 URI Routing docs : https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html